# My question was deleted and I completely disagree with the reasoning

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Here is the link to the deleted question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044460/vulnerability-vs-feature

The reason for the deletion as stated: '**opinion-based**'

But how come that a similar yet different question (as I explained in my post)
[Bug VS Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402936/bugs-versus-vulnerabilities)
is considered valid and not deleted, while at the same time mine is deleted?

Is the previous not deleted, because Jon Skeet answered there?

**If yes - that is unfair** (to say the least)

Also, the fact that my question has low number of views, doesn't mean it's not important.

In my opinion, my question is about a real issue in our industry which seems to be unsolved.

Therefore, hiding questions such as this - is wrong.

I'm asking to return the question back.

Thank you

Comment: The existence of other (off-topic) questions does not make a off-topic question on-topic. The question you link to was posted in **2008**, long before the scope of what is (and isn't) on-topic on [so] was improved.

Comment: Opinion-based is not a deletion reason. Your question was *closed* because three users thought it was opinion-based. After you doing nothing whatsoever about it for a year, it was automatically deleted as part of a clean-up process.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't aware of the deletion. Stating: _you doing nothing_ is rude.

Comment: "*The reason for the deletion as stated: 'opinion-based'*" no. that's the reason for the *closure* of the question. The reason for the deletion is that it matched [the criterial for automatic deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). The reason [from the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55044460/timeline) is RemoveDeadQuestions which is the first set of criteria listed in the help article.

Comment: Notwithstanding the age and thus rule difference, I would question whether these two questions really are similar. The "Jon Skeet" question is about two negative categories of software, which naturally overlap. The "deleted" question is about fundamentally opposite categories that only overlap due to flippant marketing rebranding.

Comment: @Larnu As in any system, the policy can change from time to time, I understand that. But why when the policy change, it doesn't affect all in the same way - that I don't understand. Double standards, maybe? Either way, my main point, as I stated above - is that I don't agree with the reasoning. I believe my question is on-topic and relevant in our industry. And therefore, should be return back.

Comment: If the rules change, that doesn't automagically get applied to any and all questions, @NikitaKurtin . In this instance, curators need to visit the question and vote to the close the question. There are **literally** *thousands* of questions posted *every day* on [so], some can and do "fall through the cracks", and if the rules change, *old* questions are much less likely to be visited than new questions. Especially when the question you link has has no activity since 2008-12-31 apart from a Community user edit on  one of the answer

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you may be right, but that doesn't make my question neither off-topic nor irrelevant in our industry.

Comment: "But why when the policy change, it doesn't affect all in the same way" Because it takes actual people to pour in their free time to put these policies into effect. Expecting volunteers to revisit of the currently 23,409,042 undeleted questions on every rule change is... unrealistic.

Comment: [so] isn't about an industry, @NikitaKurtin . It has defined on-topic (and some explicitly off-topic) subjects. Questions asking for opinions are *explicitly* off-topic, regardless of if the subject matter it's on is on-topic for [so].

Comment: @NikitaKurtin It makes your reasoning why the question should not be considered opinion-based by association baseless. That the topic is relevant to "our industry" (I doubt we work in the same industry, mind) doesn't matter at all for whether a question is suitable for SO.

Comment: @Larnu I understand what you mean, and probably some do "fall through the cracks". But specifically in case of this question - I believe it does have the right to exist, as it's indeed a real issue in our industry. After years of thinking, I believe it's a hard question, but hopefully one day someone (maybe you) will find the answer.

Comment: An issue being "real" or not does not make something on-topic, @NikitaKurtin .

Comment: How is it rude to state that you did nothing? You did, in fact, do nothing. How could you be unaware of the deletion? You said right here in *this* question that your question was deleted! Besides that, it says, right at the top of your question, in a blue banner: "It was automatically deleted 1 year ago by Community (Bot)". I'm very confused.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, by 'our industry' I mean 'software research and development'.

Comment: That isn't "my industry" though, @NikitaKurtin . I do *very little* software development, let alone software research. So am I off-topic here?

Comment: Are you being cynical or you are really don't understand what I mean?
'Unaware' is a state, which is limited in time. In regard to your initial comment: _"you doing nothing whatsoever about it for a year"_ 
Meaning, that in this year when I according to you 'did nothing', I actually did many different things. In case you aren't cynical, I'm explaining in the best way I can, that specifically to my OP, I was unaware of the deletion at that time.

Comment: A quote from the [main page of the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  site (where my OP is posted) 
_Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming_

Comment: Thereby, thinking about "software R&D industry" as "our industry", in the context of StackOverflow - it's quite logical

Comment: @NikitaKurtin "*Meaning, that in this year when I according to you 'did nothing'*" you did nothing *about the closed question*. And we know that because there was literally no activity recorded *for the question*. Please don't pull quotes out of context. Yes, of course you did "something* during that time - you'd have had breakfasts, probably travelled, met people. Yet none of that is related to changing the question *which is what is being discussed here*. I find it very hard to interpted "did nothing" as anything other than relating to the question in the context of the conversation.

Comment: I'm honestly trying to _help while working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming._   So, trying to return a relevant question related to the software industry - in my opinion - it's the right thing to do. And this is why I'm doing it and why I'm defending this opinion.

Comment: @NikitaKurtin I suggest you have a read of the [tour] again, which gives a brief overview of what is (and isn't) on-topic here.

Comment: I would say that your question is better suited at the Software-Engineering site.

Comment: [Bugs versus vulnerabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402936/bugs-versus-vulnerabilities) is not opinion based, it is a straightforward question. Your [Vulnerability VS Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044460/vulnerability-vs-feature) question is also not opinion based but with the context you give it is quite subjective and differs case by case, in fact your question already seems to answer itself and it isn't quite clear to me what the ask is. "Needs details or clarity" might have been a better close reason.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - “I'm honestly trying to help while working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.” - So instead of saying, that it’s rude to point out that you did nothing to prevent the automated deletion of a question, that wasn’t edited in over a year after its closure, you should edit the question and flag it to be undeleted. Your question won’t be restored until it can be reopened, otherwise, it will just be automatically deleted again after a year.

Comment: @SecurityHound I will try that, thanks for the informative comment.

Comment: Could a Screenshot of the deleted Question be added (to this Question), as it is not visible for Users with <10k-Rep...?

Comment: @chivracq [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFL4v.png)

Comment: Why "VS"? It is clear from context, but it may be conflated with [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). The title alone suggests a vulnerability associated with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9):

The question is off-topic for SO as almost every "A vs. B" question - opinion based and asking for an unbound list or "top of your choice" similarity/difference.

The particular "vulnerability vs. feature" question is also non-answerable as it tries to compare unrelated properties of a product - [Vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) is relatively well-defined security concept around security flaws found in a product, while [feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_feature) is vague term around "things" included (potentially intentionally) in a product.

As result I don't believe the question can be edited to be on-topic on SO. There are several other Stack Exchange sites where question may be on-topic:

- English language sites - I think that would be a best place to discuss the original statement "It is not vulnerability but a feature" - I'm sure there is a good explanation of such sentence construct where unrelated concepts are contrasted to elicit specific emotions in readers/listeners.
- Information Security would be my next choice as vulnerabilities is a common topic there. I'm not sure if trying to find difference between those two words would work there - some basic search https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=feature+vulnerability and reading their [help](https://security.stackexchange.com/help) would be a good to do before asking there
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) may be another place to ask.

For last two options coming up with solid definition of the word "feature" you are using would be useful.

Should that question be deleted - as off-topic question without answers there is no good reason to preserve it on SO (i.e. by asking for "historical lock"). I would not personally spend my delete votes on it, but since the question sat for a year without positive score it was automatically deleted without much loss for coding related Q&A.